# I am Trying to enable or create a CI for all git branches with or without pipeline in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, branch

I want to create a CI job for all my branches with or without using pipeline
SO far what i have tried .I have created two jenkins job 1) upstream job 2) downstream job, I am passing reponame and branch name from upstream job to downstream job and the downstream should trigger when there is change in the repo/branches .so when i triggered the upstream job its working fine even
it completed downstream job .Just for experiment I have triggered it again manually to check polling is working or not but i am getting Permission denied error.
Error
Using strategy: Default
[poll] Last Built Revision: Revision e7b322f3c9a42f1f17d75b19536b8037c96f5390
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified

> git --version # timeout=10
> git --version # 'git version 2.20.1'
> git ls-remote -h -- <git_url>:test.git # timeout=10
> ERROR: polling failed in  on 
> hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git ls-remote -h -- <server_url>:test.git" returned status code 128:
> stdout:
> stderr: Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied, please try again.
> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

could you please help me.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.